# Mac Studio and Macbook Pro keep losing connection to Synology NAS

Tags: network, time-machine, smb, nas

I recently got a Mac Studio and also upgraded my old Synology box (10 year old DS413) to a DS1522+.  We have used our Synology for Time Machine backups, and continue to do so, but are now seeing occasional error messages about the NAS box being ejected improperly.

It hasn't caused any noticeable problems yet, but I worry if this happens in the middle of a backup that it might corrupt the backup sparsebundle file.  This happens on both the new Mac Studio as well as at least one Macbook Pro.  The Studio is connected to the NAS box over wired ethernet, while the Macbook Pro is connected over WiFi (through Google WiFi pucks).

For what it's worth, we used to use AFP on the old NAS box, but in setting up the new one, I learned that Apple has phased AFP support out and recommends SMB - so our new setup uses SMB instead.

Mac Studio is the recent M2 Max with 12 cores running MacOS 13.5.2.

This may be more of a Synology questions, but I'm hoping someone here knows something about this that might help us figure this out.

Comment: FWIW I've been having those disconnect messages about the volume on my QNAP NAS for Time Machine for ages. Set up is similar to yours and also happened on my previous 2019 MBP as now on my M1 MBP. So whatever it is I'd be tempted to blame Apple for the issue. I've ignored the messages because Time Machine still backs up with no problems, strange.

Comment: We have the problem with Macs and Synology as well. Interestingly enough, only backups are a problem, regularly mounted SMB shares stay mounted.

Comment: @steve-chambers are you using AFP or SMB to connect?

Comment: SMB. Like I said it is set up the same way as the OP's setup as described.

Comment: The steps at the below webpage might help in troubleshooting, as might some of the author's other articles on Time Machine on NAS.
https://eclecticlight.co/2021/12/28/a-strategy-for-tackling-nas-problems/

Comment: Did you try seeing the NAS to use SMB3 only? I own a WD rather than Synology drive, but this improved connection stability significantly here, so might help in your case, too.

Comment: It does use SMB only.  My old one used AFP, but in setting up my new one, I read about the deprecation of AFP by Apple, so set it up using SMB...